# change MySQL field type if field exists

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:
`ALTER TABLE table CHANGE field1 field1 INTEGER`
Is there anyway that I can add some sort of if exists to this statement so that MySQL will make sure that field 1 exists before attempting to change its field type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ALTER TABLE` in MySql does not take an `IF EXISTS` clause.

You can do a

```
describe table
```

or

```
show columns from table
```

to get the list of all columns and then check if field1 is present before you do a `ALTER TABLE`